# Standard notation for fractional change in a value

Tags: notation

I am modeling the change in concentration of a solute as it passes through a porous medium.  The model assumes first-order decay with time.  If $p(\tau)$ is a probability density function representing the residence time distribution ("exit function") for the porous medium, the following calculation yields the mean fractional change in concentration during transit assuming a finite system with a minimum ($\tau_0$) and maximum ($\tau_n$) residence time:

$$\int_{\tau=\tau_0}^{\tau_n} p(\tau)\, e^{-kt} d\tau.$$

If the above is the RHS of an equation, is there a standard notation for a variable I can use on the LHS of an equation to denote that the variable represents the fraction change in concentration?  I am using $C$ to denote concentration, e.g.:

$$\Delta C = C\int_{\tau=\tau_0}^{\tau_n} p(\tau)\, e^{-kt} d\tau,$$

but I need a variable for the fractional change itself, and I would like the notation to reflect that it's fractional change in concentration ($C$) specifically, as I have several other fractional change variables in my model (for which I need similar notation)...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't like the tiny modification of your example: $\frac{\Delta C}{C} = \int \cdots$"?  This immediately makes me think "fractional change in $C$".  (And also logarithmic differentiation...)

Comment: I suppose I could, but I was hoping for a variable.  For instance, I use the fractional change (I'll call it $x$ for now) later on in a formula: $$ k_s = -\frac{q_{\downarrow t} + q_{\uparrow t}x}{D}.$$  It gets a little clunky to write $$  k_s = -\frac{q_{\downarrow t} + q_{\uparrow t}\frac{\Delta C}{C}}{D}.$$  This is actually a question I have often.  $\bar x$ denotes a mean and $\hat y$ denotes a predicted value.  I was hoping there was a standard notation for a fractional change in a value.